# Ensuring HTML5 FileReader Performs When .target Content Has Changed Since Last Use

Tags: javascript, html

In a website I am using HTML5, rather than .php/forms/ and clientside AJAX, to retrieve files
from my laptop's hard drive.  The page, when it loads, has a textarea in which I display the files; but here I also should note that I have other functionality, which permits me to save the contents of the textarea as a new file.  That, I do via AJAX.  Back to the chase: the "Browse" opens the Dialogue, I select a file, and the HTML5 FileRead fetches the file, all is well.

I can perform that operation as many times as I wish, no problem.  But if I then save a new file, when I next go to use the FileReader, it fails.  I have been on this for about 14 hours now, trying to discover a reason why the code behaves that way.

Without putting up a wall of code, anyone encountered a similar problem?  Ah, and the most annoying of all, is that the Dragonfly inspector is showing the textarea *textContent* as the proper data, from inside the event.target.result which works so well on the first operations after opening the page.

EDIT  ::

Unlike most of the blogs, questions and answers examples and even some spec documentation,
.textContent did not work in the context of the script I am working in, but one change as to
what specifically the data was being written AS, and all the intermittent, on again off again
FileReader behaviour, was resolved and extensive testing shows it performing 100%.

Answer (score 0):

In order to permit use of FileReader in between performing file saves out of the textarea, just had to change *textContent* to *innerText*:

```
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // note: DONE == 2
            console.log(">>>> 12 <<<< text is : "+event.target.result);
            // the textarea being edited // saved from for new files...
            // ... and used to display files read by FileReader
            document.getElementById("TextAREAx1xMAIN").textContent = event.target.result;
        }
    };
```

---

```
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
            console.log(">>>> 12 <<<< text is : "+event.target.result);
            // the textarea being edited // saved from for new files...
            // ... and used to display files read by FileReader
            document.getElementById("TextAREAx1xMAIN").innerText = event.target.result;
        }
    };
```